# How to hide and show correctly in jquery?

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, onclick, express-handlebars

I am getting data from an API using ajax and displaying movies in a list, when I click on the list I want to hide the list of shows and instead display data from another ajax call and show it when the name of the movie is clicked. Below is my code to do so.

handlebars:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TV Shows</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TV Shows</h1>
    <ul id="showList"></ul>
    <div id="show" hidden></div>
    <form id="searchForm">
        <input type="text" id="search_term">
        <label for="text">Search</label>
        <button>Submit</button>
    
    </form>
    <a id="homelink" href="#" hidden>Back to All Shows</a>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/public/js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
$(function (){
   
    let $movies = $('#showList')
    let $movie = $('#show')
    $.ajax({
        method:'GET',
        url:'http://api.tvmaze.com/shows',
        success: function(movies){
            $.each(movies, function(i,movie){
                $movies.append('<li><a href="">'+ movie.name +'</a></li>')
            })
            
        }
    
    })

    $('#showList').on('click'),function(event){

        event.preventDefault();
        $('#showList').hide();
        $('#show').empty();
        let currentLink = $(this);
        let currentId = currentLink.data('id');
        $.ajax({
            method:'GET',
            url:'http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/'+currentId,
            success: function(movies){
                $.each(movies, function(i,movie){
                    $movie.append('<h1>'+ movie.name +'</h1>')
                })
               
            }
        })
        $('#show').show();
            
    }

})
```

The links of movie list display fine but when I click on them nothing happens, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `$movies.append('<li><a href="">'+ movie.name +'</a></li>')` Doesn't appear to have a data id or a regular id on it. So this will be null/undefined. `currentLink.data('id')`

Comment: Also your click event is on the `<ul>` `$('#showList').on('click')` and it should be on the link / `<a>`. Something like ``$('#showList').on('click', 'a', function(){...})``

Comment: the movies append there is no id because it is coming from a different API path which doesn't need an id

Comment: `$('#showList').on('click'),function` has a typo / extra `,` - is this your actual code or copied/retyped for the question?  Should be `$('#showList').on('click',function() { });`

Comment: Assuming you set the event correctly then with `$('#showList').on('click')` `this` will always be `#showList` but you actually want it to be a `li` within showList - so use `event.currentTarget` to get the `li` - or use a different event handler such as `$("#showList").on("click", "li", function...` then `this` will be the `li`.

Comment: But, as pointed out earlier, your js to build the `li` doesn't include an `id` so `.data("id")` will never work.

Comment: Is data a keyword? Should it be .movies("id") in this case?